# Find maximum of $\frac{1 - \cos x}{x}$

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1-\cos x}{x}, &x \ne 0, \\ 0, &x=0. \end{cases}
$$
I want to find the maximum value of $f$.

The derivative $f'(x) = \frac{x \sin x + \cos x - 1}{x^2}$ doesn't give me much information.  It seems that its graph is increasing on $[0,1]$, so I think its maximum occurs at $x=1$.

However, is there a rigorous way to find the maximum value of the function?

Thank you.

Comment: Trig identities tell us this is equal to $2\sin^2(x/2)/x$. So you could try working with $\sin^2(u)/u$ on the interval $[0,2]$.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Actually, I'm looking for a basic simple solution and not a numerical approach.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing where you left off, let $g(x)=x\sin(x)+\cos(x)-1$.

We will show that $g(x)$ is positive, for any $x\in [0,1]$.

$g'(x)=x\cos(x)$, which is equal to $0$ for $x=0$ and strictly greater than $0$ for $x\in (0,1]$.

Therefore, $g(x)$ is strictly increasing on the interval $[0,1]$, so $g(x) > g(0)=0$, for $x \in [0,1]$.

But, $f'(x)=\frac{g(x)}{x^2} > 0$, for $x\in[0,1]$.

So $f$ is also strictly increasing on the interval $[0,1]$, which means that the maximum is $f(1)\approx 0.46$.

Comment: Hi, I know this has been a while; hope you're still here. Shouldn't we calculate $f'(0)$ separately using the limit definition of derivatives, which comes out as $\frac12$, to demonstrate that $f'(0) >0$, as the formula $f'(x) = \frac{g(x)}{x^2}$ is not defined for $x = 0$? Or alternatively, we show that $\text{max{f(x)}} = f(1)$ for $x \in (0, 1]$, and compare it with $f(0)$.

Comment: @ten_to_tenth that is completely right, had $f(0)$ been higher than $f(1)$, that would have been the maximum, so for a more rigorous proof I should have mentioned that $f(0)=0$.  But still no need to calculate $f'(0)$, we can still simply study the function and its derivative on $(0,1)$, and then look at $f(0)$ separately. Nice catch, thanks! :)